# Why can't I use this combination of operators to adapt NOR to Java

Tags: java

I learned that there's no NOR in Java and that I could use `!A && !B` or `!(A||B)`. Since both A and B are false, why can't I use `!A || B`?

Answer (score 1):

Because Java does not have a NOR operator, and your expression would be not A or B. Which is not a NOR. A NOR requires that "If both A and B are NOT true, then Q is true", so

```
if (!A && !B)
```

is a NOR. The truth table looks like

```
B A OUT
F F T
F T F
T F F
T T F
```

for your proposed solution, the truth table would be

```
B A OUT
F F T
F T F
T F T
T T T
```

Comment: But essentially A is still false, so the first truth table would still be valid. I'm just using a logical operator to reverse A's value. I thought that the operation not false OR false resulted in true.

Comment: @Arthur it does. Line three in the second truth table. Note column b is first.

Comment: So my proposed solution results in true but that doesn't mean it is considered a NOR?

Comment: Example one a nor, only line 1 is true. Ex ample two, your solution, lines 1,3 and 4 are true. Thus, your solution is wrong for two of four cases.

Answer (score 0):

Precedence of operator matters here. ! has higher precedence than ||.